# WebGL Texture malfunction

Tags: html5-canvas, textures, webgl

I am trying to get the hang of WebGL and I am following tutorial. http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=507

I got the color going but I can see the texture for some reason. I tried using a PNG, since it was showing just a black object with out adding the texture I used the image from the tutorial but still I am getting the same black cube with out the texture. I have pasted the code to the following link.

[Pastbin Link](http://pastebin.com/Cg3hcgMV)

I appreciate if someone could give me some pointers to get this working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376188/blank-texture-in-webgl

Answer (score 0):

In which browser have you tried? In Chrome textures are not showing offline, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Ive tried on both firefox and Chrome. both seems to have the same issue. Could you please explain what you mean by chrome does not show textures offline.

Comment: For security reasons Chrome does not show textures when you try to use it offline (not in a web server). Maybe you should provide a working example. There are only links for the tutorial.

Comment: oooops. Thanks for pointing that out. Instead of pasting the pastebin link ive pasted the tutorial link twice. I ll do that ASAP.

Comment: I am running on a localhost tomcat server so I do not think I am running offline.

Answer (score 0):

A possible hack solution is to start Chrome with option `--disable-web-security`.

It will give you a warning about compromised safety, so maybe you should use this only when looking at your local files...